# Netezza SQL statement to return count or null based on day of week

Tags: sql, netezza

I'm a beginner with SQL. I'm trying to determine if there's a way to write a SQL statement that will return a null value for certain days of the week, and a count on other days of the week. I can't use a script (the interface I'm using only allows me to execute a single statement).

The logic is something like this:

```
if max(as_of_date) is a Saturday or Sunday, then return null
Else select count(*) from table where (etc).
```

Comment: This whole ‘if - else’ construct only makes sense inside one row (it’s called CASE WHEN in sql) but counting only makes sense across several rows. Please supply a sample set of input rows and desired output rows, and we can certainly help

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately what I'm trying to do is to use SQL to achieve what should really be done by scheduling software.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that AS_OF_DATE is a column in your source table, and that your output should only be one row, and if even ONE row in the source table holds a record with the relevant date, then it will return non-null. Please elaborate on question (desired input/output would be nice)

```
Select 
  case when cnt>0 
  then cnt 
  end 
from
  ( select count(*) cnt 
    from THE_TABLE 
    where EXTRACT(dow FROM AS_OF_DATE) not in (1,7)
  ) x
```

Comment: The desired logic is essentially this: If Max(as_of_date) in DATE_DIM table is a Saturday or Sunday, then return null, otherwise return the result of the existing SQL (which is a single number--a count).

Comment: Is this ‘single number’ counting rows from a different table than the as_of_date column, of is the as_of_date the ‘current_date’ ?

Comment: I misstated this slightly. The actual logic is to obtain a count from a different table, joined to the date-dim table. Basically select count(*) from table-a, date-dim where table-a.as-of-date = date-dim.date and date-dim.last-process-date = ‘Y’